# How to remove reference of specific CSS files files from View

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have many JavaScript Files and CSS Files referenced in the Layout file. Now I have a couple of views which are referencing some custom libraries which are interfering with the existing CSS files. So my question is can I somehow remove those references  from these two views only or not allow them to load at all in the said views.

Comment: You want to ignore the inclusion of a css file ? or only some css style definitions from the css file ?

Comment: Some definition I guess from bootstrap

Comment: Then you can place the added css file below bootstrap.css file so the css in that file is stronger that css in bootstrap.css file

Comment: The Boot strap is adding some more style which is unacceptable. I can't undo all of them

Comment: You can use my answer than to disable bootstrap css if that does't help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, create a custom css file which overrides the existing styles from your regular (ex : bootstrap) css file. You can include this css files conditionally after your regular css styles in the views you want.

You may also use the `!important` attribute to explicitly override the values as needed.

So in your layout, add a new Section called CustomStyles

```
<head>
 <!-- Existing css include goes heree -->
    @RenderSection("CustomStyles", required: false)
</head>
```

And in your specific view, you can simply include the custom css file

```
@section CustomStyles
{
    <link href="~/MyCustomCss.css" rel="stylesheet">
}
```

**EDIT** : As per the comment.

If you are ok to completely ignore the specific css files in some views, you can update your Layout to conditionally include/exclude those.

So in your layout

```
<head>
@if (ViewBag.IncludeBootStrap == null|| (bool) ViewBag.IncludeBootStrap !=false)
{
    <link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
</head>
```

And in the view's in which you do not want to load this css file, Set the `ViewBag.IncludeBootStrap` value to `false`.

```
@{
    ViewBag.IncludeBootStrap = false;
}
<h1>This view will not use bootstrap styles</h1>
```

Comment: Your answer will definitely work. But will take a lot of effort in creating a new css file and different styles to counter effect of bootstrap.

Comment: If you are trying to **not use** a lot of bootstrap styles, but still want to include that files, That needs to be reconsidered. You need to make a compromise in one place

Comment: I'm sorry I did not have made myself clear. I need the bootstrap for many things throughout my application. but i have a couple of pages which need some different styling which bootstrap is ruining. So I needed to remove the reference from these two particular views only.

Comment: In those pages, do you need any css definition from bootstrap css files ? or are you ok to completely not load the css file for that page ?

Comment: I'm fully okay to ignore the bootstrap file all together in these two views. That's what my question is. Do we have any way to achieve that.

Comment: @AnupSharma See the updated answer which will not load the file at all for certain views.

Answer (score 1):

Give an id to the  tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" id="style1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" id="style2" />
```

And use this code:
You can use whatever event you want or just use the code without an event it's your choice

```
$("#A").click(function(){
    $("#style1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Note: While there is no disabled attribute in the HTML standard, there is a disabled attribute on the HTMLLinkElement DOM object.

The use of disabled as an HTML attribute is non-standard and only used by some Microsoft browsers. Do not use it. To achieve a similar effect, use one of the following techniques:

If the `disabled` attribute has been added directly to the element on the page, do not include the `<link>` element instead;

Set the `disabled` property of the DOM object via scripting.

Comment: Why the downvote please ? Can that user explain that ?

Comment: I'm sure he must have done it because of click function

Comment: I have just added click function for an example so he can trigger this with whatever event he wants. :)